# How to restrain each <li> element in a comment box?

Tags: html, css

This is the html code for my comment list:

```
<div id='commentbox'>
    <ul id='holder'>        
        <li class='comment'><span class='commenter'>commenter1: </span>
            <span class='commsg'>blabla1</span>
        </li>    
        <li class='comment'><span class='commenter'>commenter2: </span>
            <span class='commsg'>blabla2</span>
        </li>
        <li class='comment'><span class='commenter'>commenter3: </span>
            <span class='commsg'>blablaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa3</span>
        </li>
        <li class='comment'><span class='commenter'>commenter4: </span>
            <span class='commsg'>blabla4</span>
        </li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the css:

```
.comment{
    border-style:solid;
    width:500px;
}
.commsg{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif;
}
.commenter{
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

My problem is that if I insert a big comment like the third one, it gets out of the `<li>` border. How can I have a certain comment width?

Problem solved. Thank you both.

Comment: The answer will depend on what browsers you're supporting - so...what browsers are you supporting?

Comment: Just Firefox. It's not for commercial use.

Comment: @ddmichael Glad we could help. I'd recommend marking the answer that helped you the most as the 'answer', and upvoting any answer that is relevant and provided helpful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox your current markup and styles should work fine. The problem is, your test comment has no spaces in it, so it is treated as one word. Browsers aren't smart enough to be able to break up a word with a dash, like a word processor.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BGEz9/). Note the huge comment. It wraps just fine and leaves the `<li>` width as is.

Now check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BGEz9/1/). See how when there are no spaces in the word, it overlaps. The browser doesn't know what else to do with it.

One way around it would be to scroll the overflow from your `.comment` element:

```
overflow-x:scroll;
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BGEz9/3/). The downside is the scrollbars on each element, which don't look great, but at least get the job done if there is a huge word without spaces (such as a hyperlink, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

To make a long text without any whitespaces go to the next line, you have to add the following style to your comment-container:

```
word-wrap: word-break;
```

This will automatically break the word which is too big for the element.